# How to set up binding ViewModel properties between views

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, binding

I'm not sure how to set up view models between views, this is a smaller example of the app I'm trying to create.

I've got two views. Both views have it's own ViewModel.

The external view `ContentView` contains an inner view `StateCounterView`.

Content view has a viewModel with a `@State` property as a counter.

Every time the user taps the button, the counter increases and it should be updated in the inner view `StateCounterView`:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @State var std = 1
    
    func makeStateCounterViewModel(std:Binding<Int>) -> StateCounterViewModel {
        StateCounterViewModel(stateCounter: std)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            StateCounterView(viewModel: self.viewModel.makeStateCounterViewModel(std: self.$viewModel.std))
            Button("Increase counter") {
                self.viewModel.std += 1
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

`ContentViewModel` will provide the viewModel to create the inner view `StateCounterView`

The inner view `StateCounterView` will just show the counter and its updates.

```
class StateCounterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Binding var stateCounter: Int
    
    init(stateCounter: Binding<Int>) {
        self._stateCounter = stateCounter
    }
}

struct StateCounterView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: StateCounterViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("State counter: \(viewModel.stateCounter)")
    }
}
```

I'm using `Binding<Type>` to pass the `@State` and `@Binding` between views.

But it seems the counter won't increase in the inner view `StateCounterView`.

I've also tried to set up the viewModel with `StateObject(wrappedValue:` in a init method inside `StateCounterView` it didn't work either.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: read this info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app. Do not use `@State var std = 1` , use `@Published var ...` and do not use `@Binding` in any classes. `@State` and  `@Binding` are only to be used in `Views`. Use, for example, `@StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()` etc..

Comment: `State` and `Binding` is only for SwiftUi Views not a `class`. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) It seems like you are new to the framework

Comment: I tried and just replacing `@State` for `@Published` doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the source of truth with `@State` and pass down as `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access. In both child Views, `body` is called when the value is changed (as long as the value is being read), e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counter = 1

    var body: some View {
        ReadView(counter: counter)
        WriteView(counter: $counter)
    }
}

struct ReadView: View {
    let counter: Int
    ...
}

struct WriteView: View {
    @Binding var counter: Int
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But imagine that instead of an integer I've got a much complex object and this object comes from an external source such an endpoint for example. That why I was using VMs. My app it's much complex than the example I posted in the question. I just wanted to highlight the problem of sharing data between VMs with a simple example.

Comment: You'll have better luck with structs in SwiftUI. Use `.task` to download from your end point into a state struct.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should put all my data as State vars in the View and not having VMs with Published properties?

Comment: State vars in the View struct. The View struct is a VM already you don't need another.

Answer (score 0):

Use the example @malhal has provided. Don't overcomplicate things by introducing VMs. This is all the code you need:

```
struct CounterView: View {
    let counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(counter)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Increment") {
                counter += 1
            }
            
            CounterView(counter: counter)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code it's simplified version of the real app, I've got to use VMs because the real app it's much complex than this, but I wanted to ask about the particular problem in a generic way of sharing properties between VMs